# Nestjs: How to handle microservice MessagePattern exist from client side

Tags: microservices, nestjs, nats.io

```
 @MessagePattern({ service: 'data', slot: 'authorizeUser'})
  @UseFilters(new ExceptionFilter())
  authorizeUser(@Payload() payload: Types.IMessagePayload) {
    return this.appService.authorizeUser(payload);
  }
```

before i will call i want to check existence of MessagePattern because when pattern not exist app is hanging

```
 await this.clientProxy
      .send({ service: 'data', slot: 'findAndPopulate' }, payload)
      .toPromise();
```

I can have for each pattern his gateway and check from client with @nestjs/terminus his existence but i think it is not good solution like

```
@Get('/getSpecificUser/health')
@MessagePattern({ service: 'data', slot: 'getSpecificUser ' })
authorizeUser(@Payload() payload: Types.IMessagePayload) {
   return this.appService.authorizeUser(payload);
}


  // client
_this.health.check([() => _this.dns.pingCheck('group','/getSpecificUser/health')]);
```

is there any better solutions with nats chanels or smth else